# visual studio 2015 desktop project debugging options show only browsers

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

There's probably a really quick and easy solution to this but I was not able to find it in search. In a nutshell, created a windows 8.1 desktop project a while back in VS2013 on windows 10. Had to rebuild the win10 machine. Installed VS 2015 this time around. enable develop mode, crack open the same solution (project targets windows 8.1).....but my only debug options are my installed web browsers. It's as if VS has it confused as being a web app. Everything in the property pages looks correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated, but *Developer Mode* is required when locally deploying (side-loading) Windows Store apps for debugging. For Windows Desktop applications this settings isn't relevant. Since you didn't say so in your question: Did you upgrade the VS2013 solution to VS2015? If so, were there any errors/warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new desktop project in VS 2015, and then use a tool like winmerge or other diff tool to diff the project/solution files (your real one and the new one).  That should show you what is incorrectly making VS treat it like a web project.

Answer (score 0):

It was just me being a numb skull. Hadn't worked in VS in a while, had added a couple web projects to the solution right before walking away from it last, forgot to set windows 8 project as startup project. **smh {-_-}**